# Downloading files to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a very new user to Ubuntu so excuse me if this is a silly thing to ask.
Im using Ubuntu for Windows 10 and I have downloaded a file from AWS S3 to my windows 10 machine.
Can someone tell me how I can cd to this in Ubuntu?
I can see /home/*username*/Downloads but how can I put the S3 file in there?

Thanks

Comment: Can I confirm your objective? You downloaded a file from S3 to your Windows 10 computer, and you would like to upload this file to your Ubuntu server?

Comment: I dont have a Ubuntu server. I installed the Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10. I then downloaded an artifact from S3 to my Windows 10 machine. I'd like to know how to access this file in the Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to use Ubuntu as part of Windows Subsystem for Linux? [Perhaps this answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586455/15013618) will help.

Comment: Why is "14.04" tagged if this is a WSL system?

Comment: Thanks matigo I will try the suggestioy in your link

Comment: Thanks muru I will be sure to try those options tomorrow

Comment: excellent! /mnt worked perfectly and now I can run my file I downloaded from S3 on Ubuntu and it produces the output. Thanks!